# Webcomic from around 2014-16 about demons and pacts

Tags: story-identification, webcomics

The story was set in this world where you could make pacts or contracts with demons or something. There's magic and stuff. If you make a contract with a demon they'll obey your commands but often won't actively help you if you don't tell them to, because if you're dead then that means they're free.

The main character is this boy who is studying under some professor guy, and he ends up making this illegal contract with a super powerful demon that ends up looking like a young boy around the main character boy's age. The demon has this black, white, and red color scheme going on. The main boy is very cheerful and positive, while the demon is very grumpy.

There's a young girl whose father died while abroad, and because her father put his demon in his will for her to inherit, she goes to this court to officially inherit it or something, and make the pact or bond or whatever complete (idk if the demons get a say or not in this bond thing. Maybe they get trapped into it or tricked). I think the main character (boy) tricked his demon into a bond.

The girl has this stuffed animal that looked like a form this demon could take, which is like this salamander lizard looking thing, but when she shows up the demon looks like a humanoid man and this confuses her. It took the form of a woman with her father, and I guess also could change into the form that the stuffed animal looks like?

She asks the demon if it could have saved her father, and it says yeah, then she asks why it didn't save her father, and the demon is very like nonchalant like oh he didn't tell me to so I didn't, and I don't care that he's dead.  And this makes the girl upset because I guess she thought this demon was like friendly and nice.  And she gets mad at the demon for not helping her father and steps out of this like protective circle that she's supposed to stand in while they're making this pact or bond or whatever, which is what the demon wants so it can escape and it tries to hurt the girl I think, but the people subdue it and the judge court guy decides she's not ready to inherit the demon, and idk if they do some sort of mini pact where the demon is restricted to be in this small form or not, but the girl is upset and she doesn't want the demon.

Comment: What can you remember about the art style or color palette?  How many panels per update / size of each update page?

Comment: So probably not Ava's Demon? http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Webcomic/AvasDemon

Answer (score -3):

I was just looking for this too - was reading it a few years ago, and really liked it but then kind of stopped and forgot where it was.  I came across your post and was disappointed that it didn't lead to the answer.  But I think I found it: https://www.gunnerkrigg.com/

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  You could improve this answer by describing the features of this webcomic that match the details of the question.  Please read [answer].

Comment: Gunnerkrigg Court is a great comic, but I don't think it really matches this question. The main character isn't male, and there aren't demons under contracts to serve people. The closest thing is Reynardine, who has the power to possess other bodies, but ends up under the control of the main (female) character after he possesses a stuffed wolf toy that she owns. (But that's not related to anyone inheriting anything.)